# How to find the REST method that matches a request URI in Spring Boot within an interceptor?

Tags: spring-boot, permissions, spring-oauth2

To give you a background, we have an application with lots of REST services. Now for these services there are security permission entries. Now we could have an `AccessVoter` that intercepts all the request to check whether the user has permission to a resource but this is inefficient as we have to load thousands of rows from database and check the incoming request with the pattern saved in database. The pattern that I mentioned is exactly the same as the pattern that the developer put in their REST method, for example:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/accounts/{id}/advisers/{adviserId}")
```

Or

```
@PostMapping(value = "/accounts/{id}/advisers/address/{adrId}")
```

You can see how complex it can be and going through the records to find a match is expensive while Spring has already done the mapping and it can find the associated method very nicely.

We could create an aspect to check the permissions before the method invocation but at that time is too late as there are validation layers that happens before

I was thinking if we could have an access voter and then ask Spring to give us the method that it's going to invoke so that we can read the annotation, in above example `@PostMapping` and then find the pattern (say e.g. `/accounts/{id}/advisers/{adviserId}`) so we can only query that pattern from database, then this will be very efficient and less complex in our code.

The question is whether it's possible to get this information from Spring Boot or not?

Is there any other way than using Spring's `AccessVoter` to do the job? For example when we configure `ResourceServerConfigurationAdaptor` we have this code:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(oAuth2AuthenticationSettings.getProtectedUrlPattern().split(","))
.authenticated().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager);
```

As you can see `accessDecisionManager` is the one that returns `AccessVoter` but we could also set `.authenticated().expressionHandler(...)` which I don't know what it is used for. Can it be used for our purposes?

We don't want to use `@PreAuthorize` as it means we have to go and annotate all of our REST services.